# How do you associate a Salesforce Send with a publications list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

When defining a Salesforce Send Activity, there is no option to specify a publication list to associate with my Salesforce Data Extension.

My Goal is to have publication lists that are exposed to the default subscription center and be able to append subscribers during a Salesforce Send.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot associate a salesforce send with publications list. It's always associated at All Subscribers level and when someone unsubscribes, they get unsubscribed from all subscribers.